# Insert rows on top of current row in UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, insert

Is there a way to insert rows on top of the existing rows so that the latest data shows on the top most row? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use 

`insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`

in your .m file in the desired function call this method on the UITableView object like this

`[self.tableview insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPath withRowAnimation:YES ];`

where indexPath contains the row no.(the place were you want to place your cell)

```
NSArray *indexPath = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:2 inSection:0]];
```

Comment: Make sure that before your table view reloads its data that the new row will be reflected in your return value for `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` or you'll get an exception.